# Yii, PageCaching and multiple dependencies

Tags: php, caching, yii, yii2

Okay, so I've been looking at caching with Yii and I have a question about page caching (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-page.html).

Lets say I have a controller `PageController` with 2 actions, `PageController::actionIndex()` and `PageController::actionView($id)`.

My `behaviours()` array would look something like this:

```
'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
'only' => ['index', 'view'],
'duration' => 3600,
'variations' => [
    \Yii::$app->language,
    \Yii::$app->user->id,
],
'dependency' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
    'sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `page` WHERE `featured` = 1 AND `deleted` = 0;',
],
```

My problem is, I've got 2 actions, but the dependency for each of them is different. For index, I want to do the page count, but for view, I might want to do a select for last_updated.

```
SELECT last_updated FROM page WHERE id = 1;
```

So how do I go about making dependencies per action for page caching?

Comment: Did you try simply splitting this behavior into two behaviors?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this but you should just simply be able to do a

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
            'only' => ['index'],
            'duration' => 60,
            'variations' => [
                \Yii::$app->language,
            ],
            'dependency' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
                'sql' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post',
            ],
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\filters\PageCache',
            'only' => ['view'],
            'duration' => 60,
            'variations' => [
                \Yii::$app->language,
            ],
            'dependency' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
                'sql' => 'SELECT last_updated FROM page WHERE id = 1',
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```